# how do i adjust font size depending on device size of navigationItem.title

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a chat screen in my app where in recent iPhone the navigation title looks ok. but on an older devices like 6/7/8 the font is too big, I know .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true and .minimumScaleFactor = 0.2 can adjust the font size of uilabel but how do I do the same for navigationItem.title, adding varient to storyboard for (C,C) didn't solve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

navigation item actually has a property called titleView which you can set your custom label to

Example:

```
let myLabel = UILabel()

myLabel.text = "Custom Title"
myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
myLabel.numberOfLines = 1
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
myLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)

navigationItem.titleView = myLabel
```